React useState: How to Reset Name to "Friends" without Retaining Previous Input
I'm working on a simple React component using useState. It has an h1 tag that displays "Hello {name}", an input field where the user can type their name, and a button that changes the name to "Friends" when clicked.
Here's my current code in greetings.js:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Greetings() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const changeToFriends = () => {
    setName('Friends');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {name || '...'}</h1>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={name} 
        onChange={handleChange} 
        placeholder="Enter your name" 
      />
      <button onClick={changeToFriends}>Change Name to Friends</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Greetings;


Image for reference
The Issue:
If I type "hello" into the input field, the h1 displays "Hello hello". That part works fine.
When I click the button, it appends "Friends" to the current input, resulting in "Hello hellofriends". I want it to replace the name with "Friends" instead, so the output becomes "Hello Friends" regardless of what's in the input.
Also, if I delete the input, the h1 still displays "Hello hello" instead of clearing the name.
What I Want:
When the button is clicked, the name should be reset to "Friends" without retaining the previous input.
When the input is cleared, I want the h1 to show something like "Hello ..." or be empty, not retain the last typed value.
Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!


What I Tried:
I tried setting the state using setName to update the name when the input field changes and to replace it with "Friends" when the button is clicked.
The input field correctly updates the h1 to "Hello {name}", but when I click the button, it appends "Friends" to the input value instead of replacing it.
Also, I noticed that when I clear the input, the h1 still shows "Hello {previous value}" instead of clearing it.
What I Expected:
When I click the button, the h1 should display "Hello Friends" only, regardless of the current input.
When the input is cleared, I expected the h1 to show "Hello ..." or be empty, not retain the last typed value.
What Actually Happened:
Clicking the button appends "Friends" to the input value, resulting in "Hello hellofriends".
Clearing the input still shows "Hello {previous input}" instead of clearing the display.
Any suggestions to fix this?

I think it already works as it should : https://playcode.io/2056517 If this is correct and yours still doesn't work then could it be something else in the app?

Please review your observations.
Please review your observations as while running the same code over here, it worked the same way you have been looking for.
Please see below the test run results.
a. On loading the App

b. On typing hello

c. On clicking the button soon after the typing

d. On deleting the input

